# How to create a linked list with a loop in it?

Tags: algorithm, go, linked-list, circular-list

Determining whether a singly linked list contains a loop is a common question and how would you create a linked list with a loop? I am attempting to solve it in golang.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type node struct {
    data            int
    nextnodepointer *node
}

type linkedList struct {
    headnode *node
    length   int
}

func (l *linkedList) prepend(n *node) {
    temp := l.headnode
    if l.headnode == nil {
        fmt.Println("headnode is nil")
        fmt.Println(n)
        temp = n.nextnodepointer
    }
    l.headnode = n
    n.nextnodepointer = temp
    l.length++
}

func (l linkedList) printData() {
    toPrint := l.headnode
    for l.length != 0 {
        fmt.Printf("%v\t", toPrint)
        toPrint = toPrint.nextnodepointer
        l.length--
    }
    fmt.Println()
}

func main() {
    var n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6 *node
    myList := linkedList{}
    n6 = &node{data: 60, nextnodepointer: n3}
    n5 = &node{data: 50, nextnodepointer: n6}
    n4 = &node{data: 40, nextnodepointer: n5}
    n3 = &node{data: 30, nextnodepointer: n4}
    n2 = &node{data: 20, nextnodepointer: n3}
    n1 = &node{data: 10, nextnodepointer: n2}

    myList.prepend(n6)
    myList.prepend(n5)
    myList.prepend(n4)
    myList.prepend(n3)
    myList.prepend(n2)
    myList.prepend(n1)
    myList.printData()
}
```

So i have attempted to solve it like this, the node `n6`'s next node is `n3` but since it is not defined at that point `n3` is `nil` and this results the printData function printing the contents of the linked list like this `&{10 0xc000010240} &{20 0xc000010230}  &{30 0xc000010220}  &{40 0xc000010210}  &{50 0xc000010200}  &{60 <nil>}`. The node `n6` has next node pointer as `nil` since `n3` is `nil`. How can i create a linked list with a loop in golang?

Answer (score 0):

Simply create the loop after you created all the necessary nodes:

```
 n6 = &node{data: 60}
 n5 = &node{data: 50, nextnodepointer: n6}
 n4 = &node{data: 40, nextnodepointer: n5}
 n3 = &node{data: 30, nextnodepointer: n4}
 n6.nextnodepointer=n3
 ...
```